# Maximum of several numbers

Tags: c++

Hey guys I just completed this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a, b, c, d, e, f;
    char max;

    cout << "enter a b c: ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f;

    max = a;
    if (b > max)
        max = b;
    if (c > max)
        max = c;
    if (d > max)
        max = d;
    if (e > max)
        max = e;
    if (f > max)
        max = f;

    cout << "max is " << max << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This clearly only works for 6 entries. I want to make so if you enter 2, 3, 4, or 5 entries, it would still work! I'm guessing I have to add break, just not sure.

Comment: what about obeying to the zero-one-infinity rule and using a container/loop to make it work for any number?

Comment: Suggestion: Why not use a `char[6]` instead of having 6 different identifiers ?

Comment: Have you considered using an array to store your input values, and then looping through the array?

Comment: Mid-September 2011, a new fresh year at school begins followed by battery of useless questions on StackOverflow. Sigh ...

Comment: @plasmaHH I am not sure..but it makes sense logically..how would that look?? Mahesh I am not sure what char 6 means :s

Comment: @johnmath15: look at the title of this question. It is not helpful in any way. Titles are there for a purpose, please consider this when asking for help on this site.

Answer (score 5):

Tip: you don't actually need to store every character that is inserted.

You can simply have one variable to keep the actual "current maximum" and, every time the user inputs a new number, you compare the "current maximum" with the new number: if the current maximum is greater you simply discard the new input, if it's less, instead, the new input becomes the new maximum.

To allow the user to input how many characters he wants (until e.g. he inserts a "special" one to exit) you can use a `while` loop.

Comment: like this..: while !=0 if ((number % 10)> max) max = (number % 10); number /= 10 or did you mean something different?

Comment: Why did you put all that modulo (`%`) and division stuff? You just have to read the user input at each iteration and check if it's bigger than your current maximum...

Comment: Where's the problem? Move the `cin` inside the loop and do that check, it's not rocket science...

Answer (score 1):

You should seriously read a introductory book on c++(or any programming language).

Anyway, here's how you might do this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
char ch,max = 0;
int n=0;
cout<<"\nEnter number of characters :";
cin>>n;
cout<<"\nEnter characters\n";
while(n>0)
{
    cin>>ch;
    if(max<ch)
        max = ch;
    --n;
}

cout<<"Max : "<<max;


return 0;

}
```

Comment: @johnmath15 it's shorthand for : n = n - 1

Comment: @johnmath15 : The variable `n` is keeping track of the number of characters that you still have to enter. Each time you enter a character, there's one less left: `--n;`. The variables `i` and `n` are commonly used for "count of something", when it's clear from context what you're counting.